# Bivariate Exponentially modified Gaussian distribution in python

Tags: python, distribution, normal-distribution

I'm trying to draw contours for a exponentially modified Gaussian in 2D, in python. From wikipedia, the equation is for 1D is:

[image]

In python this looks like:

```
import scipy.special
import numpy as np

def exGauss1D(alpha, mu, sigma, x):
  co = alpha/2.0 * np.exp( alpha*mu+ alpha*alpha*sigma*sigma/2.0)
  x_erf = (mu + alpha*sigma*sigma - x)/(np.sqrt(2.0)*sigma)
  y = co * np.exp(-alpha*x) * (1.0 - scipy.special.erf(x_erf))
  return y
```

i.e.

```
x = np.arange(-10.0,10.0,0.1)
exGauss1D(4, 0, 0.1, x)
```

will output some numbers that you can plot as a nice 1D distribution.
Now, how to extrapolate this to 2-D over a grid and draw contours?

My code looks like this:

```
N = 60
X = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
Y = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# ex-Gaussian distribution
def exGauss2D(alpha, mu, sigma):
   pos = np.empty(X.shape + (2,))
   pos[:, :, 0] = X
   pos[:, :, 1] = Y

  sigma_det = np.linalg.det(sigma)
  exp_component = (alpha*mu+ alpha*alpha*sigma_det/2.0)
  coef = alpha/2.0 * np.exp(exp_component)

  # Should be (mu + alpha*sigma*sigma - x)
  m1 = mu + alpha*sigma_det - pos

  x_erf = (m1)/(np.sqrt(2.0)*sigma_det)
  m2 = coef * np.exp(-alpha*pos)

  error_function = (1.0 - scipy.special.erf(x_erf))
  z = np.einsum('...k,...l->...', m2, error_function)
  return z

# input parameters
alpha = 0.05# index of the exponential function
mu = np.array([5., 5.])
sigma = np.array([[ 4 , -2.0], [-3,  10.3]])

# convolve
exGauss2D = exGauss2D(alpha, mu, sigma)
# # plot result
plt.contour(X,Y,exGauss2D,colors='blue')
plt.plot(mu[0], mu[1], 'bo')
```

The output looks like:
[image]

which doesn't look quite right to me, given that with the same mu and sigma parameters, the 2D Gaussian looks like: 
[image]

I would have assumed the 2d ExGauss would have been a slightly shifted to one side form of the 2d Gauss?
So either my assumption or my exGauss2D function is wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: this question seems to be about maths, not programming. If this is not the case, you should rephrase it, so that it becomes clear that you have a programming problem. otherwise it will be closed

Comment: if it is about maths, you should take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/